# Column sorting in PostgreSQL is different between macOS and Ubuntu using same collation

Tags: postgresql, collation

I created a database with UTF8 encoding and fr_FR collation on both my Mac and Ubuntu server like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database OWNER 'admin' TEMPLATE 'template0' ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE 'fr_FR.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE 'fr_FR.UTF-8';
```

On both, I queried the collation:

```
show lc_collate;
```

and obtained:

```
fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Then, I tried to sort the same database and didn't obtain same results:

```
SELECT winery FROM usr_wines WHERE user_id=1 AND status=1 ORDER BY winery LIMIT 5;
```

1 - On macOS:

```
 a space before the a
A New record
Aa
Altesinoo
Aé
```

2- On Ubuntu 14.04:

```
Aa
Aé
Altesino
A New Wine
 a space before a
```

On Ubuntu, I have installed the desired locales and create a new collation:

```
CREATE COLLATION "fr_FR.utf8" (LOCALE = "fr_FR.utf8")

select * from pg_collation;

  collname  | collnamespace | collowner | collencoding | collcollate | collctype  
------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------
 default    |            11 |        10 |           -1 |             | 
 C          |            11 |        10 |           -1 | C           | C
 POSIX      |            11 |        10 |           -1 | POSIX       | POSIX
 C.UTF-8    |            11 |        10 |            6 | C.UTF-8     | C.UTF-8
 en_US      |            11 |        10 |            6 | en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf8
 en_US.utf8 |            11 |        10 |            6 | en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf8
 ucs_basic  |            11 |        10 |            6 | C           | C
 fr_FR      |          2200 |        10 |            6 | fr_FR.utf8  | fr_FR.utf8
```

On the mac, the fr_FR collation was already installed.

So why this difference in sorting ?

Another strange issue on Ubuntu: I fi tried to force the collation in my request:

```
SELECT winery FROM usr_wines WHERE user_id=1 AND status=1 ORDER BY winery COLLATE "fr_FR" LIMIT 5;
```

I got:

> ERROR:  collation "fr_FR" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist

Any help is welcome.

Comment: it known issue - only collation `C` will give same result, as it relies on postgres , not on OS

Comment: You mean there is no way to see same sorting on all platforms using same language collation, except with C collation ? This seems ver strange. I didn't have this behaviour using MySQL unicode collation for example.

Comment: maybe mysql does not use os collation then?..

Answer (score 1):

**COLLATE "C" will give you predictable results on all platforms.** [Additional collations may be available depending on operating system support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html). And thus its behaviour totally depends on OS.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html:

> On all platforms, the collations named default, C, and POSIX are
>   available. Additional collations may be available depending on
>   operating system support. The default collation selects the LC_COLLATE
>   and LC_CTYPE values specified at database creation time. The C and
>   POSIX collations both specify "traditional C" behavior, in which only
>   the ASCII letters "A" through "Z" are treated as letters, and sorting
>   is done strictly by character code byte values.
>
> If the operating system provides support for using multiple locales
>   within a single program (newlocale and related functions), then when a
>   database cluster is initialized, initdb populates the system catalog
>   pg_collation with collations based on all the locales it finds on the
>   operating system at the time. For example, the operating system might
>   provide a locale named de_DE.utf8. initdb would then create a
>   collation named de_DE.utf8 for encoding UTF8 that has both LC_COLLATE
>   and LC_CTYPE set to de_DE.utf8. It will also create a collation with
>   the .utf8 tag stripped off the name. So you could also use the
>   collation under the name de_DE, which is less cumbersome to write and
>   makes the name less encoding-dependent. Note that, nevertheless, the
>   initial set of collation names is platform-dependent.